# Problema Spring Security Override

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Estou tentando implementar o Spring Security...só que estou tendo problema com a configuração dele, o @Override não funciona de forma nenhum, e por causa disso ele não pega o usuário criado em memória, e muito menos muda as configurações padrões de permissão e tal.

Eu criei um projeto novo só com SPRING MVC+ Soring Boot + Spring Security, só para ver se consigo usar ele, mais o problema persiste.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Eu não sei se está faltando alguma configuração, mais pelo que andei pesquisando, essa configuração básica aí, deveria aparece um alert para botar o login que eu criei em memória...só que nada acontece.

Quando eu rodo o projeto cria a senha padrão do Spring e a tela de login é uma tela bonitinha web, e não um alert.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.

O pacote config estava em lugar errado, tem que estar no mesmo lugar da main, ou tenho que usar uma annotation de nome @ComponenteScan

A solução achei nesse post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072517/unable-to-override-spring-boots-default-security-configuration